# Is there any option to check whether the URL is working or not? before passing it to the next function in scrapy , Python

Tags: python, parsing, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

I have 2 function blocks in my scraper
1.Parse
2.Parse_info

In the 1st block, I got the list of URLs.
Some of the URLs are working (they already have the 'https://www.example.com/' part)
Rest URLs are not working (they do not have the 'https://www.example.com/' part)

So before passing the URL to 2nd block i.e. parse_info; I want to validate the URL
and If it is not working I want to edit it and add the required part ('https://www.example.com/' part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leverage the requests module and get the status code of the website - a guide to doing that is [here](https://realpython.com/python-requests/#:%7E:text=The%20first%20bit%20of%20information,looking%20for%20was%20not%20found).

Similarly, if you're just trying to validate whether the URL contains a specific portion i.e the 'https://www.example.com/', you can perform a regex query and do that.

Comment: The 'regex query' worked for me. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation from your question is that you have a list of URLs, some of which have an absolute address like 'https://www.example.com/xyz' and some only have a relative reference like '/xyz' that belongs to the 'https://www.example.com' site.

If that is the case, you can use 'urljoin' to rationalise each of the URLs, for example:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urljoin

>>> url = 'https://www.example.com/xyz'
>>> print(urljoin('https://www.example.com', url))
https://www.example.com/xyz

>>> url = '/xyz'
>>> print(urljoin('https://www.example.com', url))
https://www.example.com/xyz
```

Comment: Yes, I am using urljoin() but before that, 
I wanted to validate the URL; that whether the 'https://www.example.com' part is already present.